# How to modify Start Without Debugger script for python in MS Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently installed MS Visual Studio Code for the first time (we'll be using it on an upcoming project). I wrote a simple Hello, World program in python and clicked Debug > Start Without Debugging. MSVSC runs the program just fine, but after that it runs a couple more commands, one of which generates an error (see below). These commands are unnecessary and the error is ugly and distracting.

Where is the script that MSVSC is running? I want to remove those two useless lines.

```
PS C:\Users\me> cd 'c:\Users\me\Documents\my-project'; ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\Users\me\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.12954\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py' '--default' '--nodebug' '--client' '--host' 'localhost' '--port' '51699' 'c:\Users\me\Documents\my-project\hello.py'
hello, world
distance 5.0
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\my-project> C:/Users/me/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\my-project> conda activate base
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ conda activate base
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\me\Documents\my-project>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not useless, you just happened to be running a file that happens to not need a specific conda environment activated. It's a general problem with conda that [we're trying to solve](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5344). The smoothest experience would be to use virtual environments if that will work for you.

Comment: OK, so "useless" commentary aside, are you saying that there is no way to edit the command set that gets executed here?

Comment: You can [turn off environment activation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) with `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false` if that's what you're after.